# How to reduce amount of space between lines of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In fiddle I'm attempting to reduce the amount of space between each sentence in each question option (options are the blue text):

http://jsfiddle.net/25LjE/79/

I'm reducing the height of class `pds-answer-group` using the `line-height` property :

```
.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
line-height:50%;
}
```

But the amount of space between the lines is not being reduced. How can the CSS be updated to reduce the amount of space between each line of text for the question options?

CSS behind the fiddle:

```
.pds-question-top {
font-size:10pt !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-pd-link, .pds-comments {
display:none !important;
}

.pds-box {
width:220px !important;
}

.pds-input-label {
width:85% !important;
}

.PDS_Poll {
margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-answer-span {
color:#00f;
}

.pds-vote {
background-color:#424242;
}

.pds-answer-text {
color:#00f;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-answer-feedback {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-votebutton-outer {
text-align:center;
}

.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
}

.pds-input-label,.pds-answer-input {
float:left;
}

.pds-view-results,.pds-links {
color:#FFF !important;
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
}

.pds-comments,.pds-return-poll {
color:#FFF !important;
}

.pds-links {
    display: inline !important;
}
.pds-pd-link {
display: none !important;
}
.pds-box {
    width: 220px !important;
}
.pds-input-label{
    width: auto! important;
}
.PDS_Poll{
    margin-bottom:15px;
}

.pds-question-top {padding:0 !important}
```

HTML behind the fiddle:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/6352993.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/6352993/">This is very long test question to test how polldaddy handles questions that exceed that normal length............ yes a very long question indeed..............</a></noscript>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pds-question-inner').prepend('<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;font-size: 15px;float:left">Header</span>');
});
```

Comment: @Andrew Peacock thats what ive tried but it does;nt seem to work in this case

Comment: Before doing anything else, clean that code up, it will keep causing you problems ahead, trust me. Overwriting styling in general, and overwriting styling using !important in particular is not a sustainable solution. An example: you assign spans the class of .pds-answer-group, which is then overwritten by this selector styling the parent of the span: "#PDI_container6352993 .pds-answer label" - this keeps your code complicated and hard to reuse. Redo and do it right :)

Comment: Using `!important` in your CSS is usually a sign that something somewhere is wrong. Using it a lot is a sign that something is badly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your CSS is being overridden by the `.pds-input-label` class. It might be loaded from the JS file you're using. Just add `line-height: 50% !important;` to the `.pds-input-label` class. See the example here http://jsfiddle.net/2Wrhd/

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the `line-height` in your CSS, depending on the text that you want to decrease the space in between.

**Example:**

```
.pds-answer-group {
padding-top:1px !important;
padding-bottom:1px !important;
margin-top:1px !important;
margin-bottom:1px !important;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
line-height:9pt /* worked when i changed this from 50% */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact the problematic element is:

```css
.pds-answer-span {
  line-height: 150% !important;
}
```

You can easily check it in Firefox with Ctrl+Shift+i (and redefine it to 100% lower the lines).

Answer (score 0):

I tried and worked. Put span in

```
<p></p>
```

and set line-height property:

```
<p style="line-height: 2pt';"><span class="pds-answer-span">blablabla</span></p>
```